# Is it possible to edit code in R that has already been executed? (If so how?)

Tags: r

I am new to R, and I cant seem to be able to edit code in the console once it has already been executed, so I am wasting a lot of time rewriting long bits of code every time I want to alter a small mistake. 
If there was a way around this is would save me (and anyone else struggling with this) so much time! 
thanks

Comment: What are you using? RStudio? Use a editor as suggested by @s.brunel.

Comment: dont type in the console use a script editor

Comment: In the console, press the up key to retrieve and edit earlier code submissions. This won't cancel out what the prior commands did, however. Also, of course, just use a script as s.brunel suggested.

Comment: thank you both so much! this is so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you should really consider using RStudio, you can highlight and run individual lines (Ctrl+Enter), make edits to specific portions of your code, and save your .R files locally on your machine.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484448-Editing-and-Executing-Code